# How would I share ports between my IIS applications?

Tags: iis

By request of our network administrator, I would like to do so unless someone could give me a strong argument against it.

- What should i watch out for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this is by creating a unique binding. If the port and IP are the same, the host header (dns entry) must be different.

I am unaware of any downsides to this approach. Especially if you do not have enough IPs to service every application you need to run.